# About React-Native design. Using view On top of other

Tags: react-native

[project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnCbu.png)

I would like to know from you if there is any way to make this screen better. That can be responsive for either mobile or tablet.Below the image as it should look. Should I use absolute for all items?? Is there any way to make this more responsive??

[project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s9dv.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import {} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
const Login = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          position: 'absolute',
          top: '40%',
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          borderTopLeftRadius: 50,
          borderTopRightRadius: 50,
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'relative',
            top: '10%',
            marginHorizontal: 30,
            marginVertical: 20,
          }}>
          <Text>Email</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Email"
            style={{borderColor: 'gray', borderBottomWidth: 2}}
          />
        </View>

        <View
          style={{
            position: 'relative',
            top: '10%',
            marginHorizontal: 30,
            marginVertical: 20,
          }}>
          <Text>Password</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Password"
            style={{borderColor: 'gray', borderBottomWidth: 2}}
          />
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'relative',
            top: '10%',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            width: 150,
            height: 50,
            backgroundColor: 'Black',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            borderRadius: 40,
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Could someone show me a better way to make this more responsive for mobile and tablet? For the part of figure 2 where it shows the circle. Is there a better way to do it? Or will I have to use Absolute Position for everything?? Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can, using `justifyContent: 'flex-end'` in `View` parent style which looks like:

```js
<View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          }}
        >
{...view input email password here...}<View/>
```